# Java toString representations across Java virtual machine implementations?

Tags: java, jvm

With most core libraries and Java classes, are 'toString' representations standard across all Java implementations.  Or is this not specified in the Java spec.

For example, if I do, new HashMap()/toString , is the output from OpenJDK expected to be the same with IBM jrockit.

Should they be compatible?  It may be an issue if you are porting code from one JVM to the other and expected the string representation to be the same.

Comment: They should be consistent only when the documentation says so. In the case of `HashMap` which extends from `AbstractMap` the output of [`toString()` is defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString%28%29)  and should be consistent across JVM implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `toString()` methods is (with few exceptions) unspecified, and therefore in theory could vary from one implementation of Java to the next.

However, *most commercial* Java implementations have class libraries that are derived from some version of the Sun / Oracle class libraries, be it the OpenJDK codebase or an earlier one.  Given that Sun / Oracle are cautious about deliberately making changes that could break customer code, I would *expect* the respective `toString()` methods to be mostly compatible.

But there are some notable exceptions; e.g. java implementations based on the GNU Classpath libraries, the Apache Harvest libraries and ... Android.  Note that these implementations don't pass the Java compliance tests (because Oracle refuses to licence the TDK under acceptable terms!!) so strictly speaking they can't be called Java(tm).

The bottom line is that dependence on *undocumented* `toString()` formats *could* lead to porting problems or problems when upgrading JVM versions.  But in reality, the chance of problems depends critically on what you are porting from and to.  If you stick to JVMs that use Oracle / Sun derived class libraries, the chance of problems is small.

---

So what should you do about this?

The most extreme position would be to avoid using `toString` methods (implicitly or explicitly), except in cases where the output format is specified.  But I think that goes too far.  (And it could be hard to enforce this policy ...)

A more realistic position would be to avoid using `toString` methods in cases where the precise output format matters.  In other words:

- Don't use `toString()` in object serialization schemes ... unless the format is specified.
- If you use `toString()` in unit testing, be aware that you may need to fix non-portable unit tests as part of a porting effort.

Comment: +1 While you shouldn't expect the output of toString to be significantly different between JVMs, it should treated as way of logging the contents of the String and you should not need it to be exactly the same across all implementation. It is not a means of serializing the contents.

Comment: "The bottom line is that dependence on toString() formats could lead to porting problems."  Like you said, it could lead to potential problems just like any porting or even JVM upgrades could lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and I would say that's Implementation Dependent. No formal specification exists. Although, books like [http://www.amazon.com/The-Java-Class-Libraries-Volume/dp/0201310023](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310023) clearly identify what a library will do, does not necessarily say "should do".

So, implementors are free to choose and document what `toString()` displays, but make no guarantees for display to be the same across other JVM implementations.

To solve your problem, the only way to be sure of `toString()` implementations is to `@Override` `public String toString()` method in your derived classes(yes you'll have to derive each class you want `toString()` for) and explicitly specify its output.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't *expect the string output [of the toString() method] to be the same*. Content and format of the methods are not specified (look at the associated javaDoc).

It is not even guaranteed, that the implementation is the same for different versions from the same vendor. So never ever compare instances by the result of the `toString()` or use those results as keys in databases or identifiers in general. They're just *a* textual representation of the instance. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4) says:

> 1.4. Relationship to Predefined Classes and Interfaces
>
> As noted above, this specification often refers to classes of the Java
>   SE platform API. In particular, some classes have a special
>   relationship with the Java programming language. Examples include
>   classes such as Object, Class, ClassLoader, String, Thread, and the
>   classes and interfaces in package java.lang.reflect, among others.
>   This specification constrains the behavior of such classes and
>   interfaces, but does not provide a complete specification for them.
>   The reader is referred to the Java SE platform API documentation.

So ... no, there is no specification that requires what you describe.